# ArgumentError during creation of many EC2 instances using knife

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife

I'm invoking "knife ec2 server create" to create many ec2 instances with a delay of 10 seconds. It works well for few instances (approx. 10). However, if I create more instances (in the order of 30), I start getting the following argument error:

```
   .INFO: SIGHUP received, reconfiguring
   ERROR: ArgumentError: You must pass :on, :tail, or :head to :on
```

The error seems to happen during random phases. Sometimes while waiting for the ec2 instance, sometimes later when executing my recipe.

Is there a limit of knife processes or chef api calls I should have running at the same time?

Comment: Why are you launching instances with a delay between them?  Also, I'm assuming that you know you can launch multiple instances (of the same AMI) in the same API call.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this has nothing to do with Chef (although the error you're getting is being swallowed by Chef). I think the EC2 API is rate limiting you. You may need to add a splay or delay between calls or perform them in smaller batches.

If you are continuing to experience this error, I would recommend opening a ticket at https://tickets.opscode.com

Comment: I already put delays into the scripts. It seems like there is no interaction with the EC2 API happening anymore at the time the error  is raised. The error is raised when Chef is bootstrapping a machine or executing some recipes.

Comment: If you are continuing to experience this error, I would recommend opening a ticket at tickets.opscode.com then.